# in ExtJS, is it better to call Model.save() or Store.Sync()?

Tags: extjs

And what are the ramifications of each?

I see that `Model.save()`, for example, automatically refreshes the Model with results from the server. I'm not sure if `sync()` does.

Comment: please mark answered questions accepted

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> automatically refreshes the Model with results from the server

`Store.sync()` refreshes modified records as well (provided you have setup the server response correctly).

So, technically, both methods do the same. However, in my opinion, you can use `Model.save()` only in one case: when you don't have `store`. Why? Because when you have store and nevertheless you use `Model.save()` that's mean that you have setup connection (proxy) configuration for both `store` and `model`. And that's mean that you have duplicated code which is potentially harder to maintain.

So, to summarize, you use `Model.save()` only if you use **standalone model**, without store (it may be the case when you have `form` which is not connected to any grid. So you create standalone model for such form), and you use `Store.sync()` in other cases.

Comment: What response does Store.sync() expects as successful and what as error prone?

Comment: @UmairAshraf, it expects list of modified records in the same format as reader would expect. Also response may contain `success: true` and `message`. Take a look at requests-responses at [this example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/writer/writer.html)

Comment: You also could have a proxy defined on model which would eliminate the duplicate code, right?